# using unordered map find function

Tags: c++, find, unordered-map

If I want the unordered map find function to return a bool value, how would I go about doing that?

Here's my code right now.

```
bool NS_SymbolTable::SymbolTable::Contains(std::string lexeme)
    {
        SymbolTable *tempSymbolTable = this;
        std::unordered_map<std::string, Identifier*>::iterator it = tempSymbolTable->hashtable.find(lexeme);

        return std::boolalpha;
    }
```

What else do I neeed to do ? Is it possible to return a bool? There is little to no documentation on this that I have found.

This is where I got an example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982431.aspx

Comment: Whatm exactly, do you think `std::boolalpha` signifies? It’s not a boolean value …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation look [std::unordered_map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find). There it says:

> Return value
>   iterator to an elements with key key. If no such element is found, past-the-end (see end()) iterator is returned.

To get boolean value indicating whether an element is present, use

```
bool contained = it != tempSymbolTable->hashtable.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

`tempSymbolTable->hashtable.find(lexeme)` will return `tempSymbolTable->hashtable.end()` if it fails, so you can convert this result to a bool very simply:

```
return tempSymbolTable->hashtable.find(lexeme) != tempSymbolTable->hashtable.end();
```

Also, assigning this to a temporary variable and working through that is unnecessary. Your function can be reduced to:

```
bool NS_SymbolTable::SymbolTable::Contains(std::string lexeme)
{
    return hashtable.find(lexeme) != hashtable.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool NS_SymbolTable::SymbolTable::Contains(std::string lexeme)
{
    SymbolTable *tempSymbolTable = this;
    return tempSymbolTable->hashtable.end() != tempSymbolTable->hashtable.find(lexeme);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the return value of find against tempSymbolTable->hastable.end(), if they are equal then it did not find your element. The reason find works like this is because in its current form it is more general than something that returns only a bool.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_map::find()`, like the rest of the standard containers' find functions, returns `end()` on failure.

Try this:

```
bool NS_SymbolTable::SymbolTable::Contains(std::string lexeme)
{
  SymbolTable *tempSymbolTable = this;
  std::unordered_map<std::string, Identifier*>::iterator it = 
    tempSymbolTable->hashtable.find(lexeme);

  return it != tempSymbolTable->hashtable.end();
}
```

Reference:

- [MSDN unordered_map::find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982431.aspx)
- [MSDN unordered_map::equal_range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982057.aspx)

**EDIT**: change sense of return value.

Comment: Your logic is reversed. This will return true if the map does not contain the string.

Comment: did you mean `it != tempSymbolTable->hashtable.end()`?  The name of the function is `Contains()`, returning `false` would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. He said he wanted it to return a bool, he didn't say what value it should have :)